# Formating output of a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I'm attempting to read from a list of servers using  a text file called servers.txt. I need to list the unc paths(example would be \\server1\C:\temp) in an text format after pulling the results. I've come up with the following below , but having trouble on how to get the host and path formatted. Any help would be much appreciated.I'm not allowed to use powershell in this instance.

```
for /f %%i in (C:\\temp\servers.txt) do 

net view \\%%i  /all  >> unc.txt
```

Comment: Hi @cmoney2123, welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve readability of your question, consider enclosing code fragments in back tics ( ` ), or indenting code lines 4 spaces.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding host, path and `\\server1\C:\temp` but your basic command should look like this: `(For /F "UseBackQDelims=" %%A In ("C:\temp\servers.txt") Do Net View \\%%A /All)>"UNC.txt"`

Comment: The `NET` command has to be on the same line as the `FOR` command.

Comment: ... or enclosed in parentheses with the left paren in the same line as `FOR` command.